# can we create datasync between two tables without indexes in azure data sync

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

can we sync two tables of two different databases in azure without indexes. As, we all know ,if two databases has to be in sync hub database and member data base should have same schema. But is there chance of avoiding indexes.
please help  me with this

Comment: Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922874/azure-data-sync-clustered-index-error why you want to avoid the index?

Answer (score 0):

Each table needs to have a primary key and you cannot avoid that. Please read the following excerpt from Microsoft documentation:

> Each table must have a primary key. Don't change the value of the
>   primary key in any row. If you have to change a primary key value,
>   delete the row and recreate it with the new primary key value.

Source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#sync-req-lim).